# area chart with d3 is not rendering on jsp page but working fine with html

Tags: javascript, jsp, d3.js

i sucessfully rendered d3js area chart in a html page here is the code which is rendering sucessfully in chrome or mozilla.The name of the file is say temp.html.Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<title>js graphs and charts libraries</title>
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="dbar">

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var margin = {top:10, right: 20, bottom: 30,left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var svg = d3.select ("#dbar").append("svg").attr("width",
width+margin.left+margin.right).attr("height",height+margin.top+margin.bottom)
.append("g").
attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")");
 var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%Y").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var area = d3.svg.area().x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                .y0(height)
                .y1(function(d) { return y(d.count); });
d3.json("data/json.json", function(error, data) {
      data.StoreVisitGraphCount.list.forEach(function(d) {

        d.date = parseDate(d.date);

        d.count = +d.count;
      });
      //console.log(data.StoreVisitGraphCount.list);
    x.domain(d3.extent(data.StoreVisitGraphCount.list, function(d) {
return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data.StoreVisitGraphCount.list, function(d) { 
return d.count; })]);
console.log(data.StoreVisitGraphCount.list);
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data.StoreVisitGraphCount.list)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when i am copy pasting this code to say "temp.jsp" page its not rendering and chart is not coming.I am running this page on tomcat server.

need suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not because you saved it as jsp or html page. You need to add charset="UTF-8" to your script declaration as d3.js uses UTF characters.

eg.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: This answer is correct. But, if you need a quick hack, you can use d3.v3.min.js - the minimized version - which seems to remove characters like 'pi'.